# ForkJoin vs other thread pools in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java ForkJoin pools has been compared to the other "classic" thread pool implementation in Java many times. The question I have is slightly different though:

Can I use a single, shared  ForkJoin pool for an application that have BOTH types of thread usage - long running, socket-handling, transactional threads, AND short running tasks (CompletableFuture)? Or do I have to go through the pain of maintaining 2 separate pools for each type of need?
... In other words, is there a significant (performance?) penalty, if ForkJoin is used in place where other Java thread pool implementations suffice?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the [`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool())? Don't know much about it myself, but this website has some things to say about it: https://dzone.com/articles/be-aware-of-forkjoinpoolcommonpool

Comment: Thanks for the dzone article! I have seen in the past, but did not occur to me  today!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html), it depends:

> (3) Unless the ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker API is used, or the number of possibly blocked tasks is known to be less than the pool's ForkJoinPool.getParallelism() level, the pool cannot guarantee that enough threads will be available to ensure progress or good performance.

The parallelism is coupled to the amount of available CPU cores. So given enough CPU cores and not to many blocking I/O tasks, you could use the [commonPool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()). It does not mean you should though. For one thing, `ForkJoinPool` is explicitly not designed for long running (blocking) tasks. For another thing, you probably want to do something with long running (blocking) tasks during shutdown.

Comment: FWIW, what `ForkJoinPool` apparently _is_ optimized for, is executing tasks that submit other tasks. When that happens, the `execute(...)` methods can choose whether to put the new task into the queue or, to just execute it in the calling thread before returning.

Comment: Let me share some more details: